# Fail to run mlDeploy to Remove ML server on Azure due to connect time out

Tags: azure, gradle, marklogic-10

I am trying to deploy ML changes via gradle from a central management cloud pc.

I could successful do a fresh deploy on a new ML installation on that cloud pc.
However I could not deploy to an ML server on Azure due to connection timeout.
(I have try to run the same `gradlw -i mlDeploy` more than 10 times. They all result the same error.)

[image]

I notice most of the other things like content db, module db, schema db, app servers, users, roles are all successfully deployed. I suspect it might to to the **mlLoadModules**.

If I run `gradlew -i mlLoadModules` to that remote Azure ML server. I will get the same time out error.
[image]

How to resolve the problem? Can I change the timeout setting in mlgradle?
(I really do not want to run the Gradle from that Azure ML server. I prefer that central deployment node concept.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.
It is not a mlgradle problem.

The issue was caused by the firewall on the Azure ML host.
It seems **mlLoadModules** needs to communicate with the application REST port to upload the Xquery programs. That application REST port is not yet configured to be open in the default Azure ML ARM template from the marklogic official image.

After openning the application REST point, for my case, it is PORT 8030, I could run `gradlew -i mlDeploy` successfully.